# flink run -py wordcount.py caused NullPointerException

Tags: python, apache-flink

i want to process data with flink's python api on windows . But when i use the command to submit a job to Local cluster, it throws NullPointerException。

```
bin/flink run -py D:\workspace\python-test\flink-test.py
```

flink-test.py：

```
from pyflink.dataset import ExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import TableConfig, DataTypes, BatchTableEnvironment
from pyflink.table.descriptors import Schema, OldCsv, FileSystem

exec_env = ExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
exec_env.set_parallelism(1)
t_config = TableConfig()
t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(exec_env, t_config)

t_env.connect(FileSystem().path('D:\\workspace\\python-test\\data.txt')) \
    .with_format(OldCsv()
                 .line_delimiter(' ')
                 .field('word', DataTypes.STRING())) \
    .with_schema(Schema()
                 .field('word', DataTypes.STRING())) \
    .register_table_source('mySource')

t_env.connect(FileSystem().path('D:\\workspace\\python-test\\result.txt')) \
    .with_format(OldCsv()
                 .field_delimiter('\t')
                 .field('word', DataTypes.STRING())
                 .field('count', DataTypes.BIGINT())) \
    .with_schema(Schema()
                 .field('word', DataTypes.STRING())
                 .field('count', DataTypes.BIGINT())) \
    .register_table_sink('mySink')

t_env.scan('mySource') \
    .group_by('word') \
    .select('word, count(1)') \
    .insert_into('mySink')

t_env.execute("tutorial_job")
```

[image]
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you using Jython ??

Comment: no,  my flink version is 1.9.1, it should be py4j ？

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I read the source code by the error message.

[image]

The NullPointerException is caused by that flinkOptPath is empty!. I use the flink.bat to submit the job , and the flink.bat don't set the flinkOptPath. So I add some code in the flink.bat like this . The flink.bat is Incomplete for now. we should run flink on linux.
[image]